# Get JSON String in java with org.json

Tags: java, json, org.json

```
[{"post":{"titel":"Glee","interpret":"Bran Van 3000","jahr":"1997","id":"5"}},{"post":{"titel":"Goodbye Country (Hello Nightclub)","interpret":"Groove Armada","jahr":"2001","id":"4"}},{"post":{"titel":"Beauty","interpret":"Ryuichi Sakamoto","jahr":"1990","id":"1"}}]
```

The above string is what i have in json and now what i want to do is to just get  the values of "post" and "titel" as in the above string what i am having 3 values of post which makes sense to me. But, now what i want is to print all the 3 values of post and each value in the post string.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            columns = new String[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                columns[i]=jsonObject.getString("post");
            }
```

above code returns me 3 values of post. WHat i can do if i want to print values of post and the each value of column in post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this (I don't use the `columns` array just to print, and this code is not tested):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject postObj = jsonObject.getJSONObject("post");
    for (String i : postObj.keys()) {
         System.out.println("Key: " + i + "; Value: " + postObj.getString(i));
    }
}
```

That is, process each element of the Object returned by the "post" object of each array element.